# Cant install wireshark - failed to load xcb plugin

Tags: qt, qt5, wireshark

I have installed wireshark 2.2.6:

```
$ sudo apt install -y wireshark 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wireshark is already the newest version (2.2.6+g32dac6a-1~xenial1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
```

Im running ubuntu 16.04 and when I try to launch the app I get:

```
$ wireshark
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
```

The only way to get around this, for me, is to

```
sudo QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ wireshark
```

But then the UI looks awful and worse than I remember...
Is there a way to permanently solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As noted on the [Qt Forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/71369/failed-to-load-qt-platform-plugin-xcb/3), just add the following code to your **~/.bashrc** file:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/appname/libs/Qt/plugins/platforms
```

replacing **appname** with your app's name. There should be a file called **libqxcb.so** within the **platforms** folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Wireshark 2.6.10. I thought I'd post my solution in case it could help somebody else.

First, it complained about an "error while loading shared libraries: libdouble-conversion.so.1". I used `apt install libdouble-conversion1` and the error went away, but was replaced with:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Wireshark, to no avail. Finally, I uninstalled `libdouble-conversion1`, and then used `apt autoremove`. I reinstalled Wireshark (`apt install wireshark`), and now it works fine.

I think the libdouble library must have been corrupted or something, and when I reinstalled it manually, I used a package that was missing something important for Wireshark. Uninstalling the libdouble library meant that a fresh Wireshark install would install a package containing what it needed.